# How to get data from two tables like one table all rows and with respect to first table primary key sum of row from other table

Tags: php, mysql

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2:**

[image]

**Result table:**

[image]

I am in the need of efficient result as my original table one have 100 columns so I need to use aysteric (*). I'm currently working in `mysql`.

Comment: Have you made any effort to try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: yes i wa trying to use subquerries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly join sum of expense table of each user by using below query.

```
SELECT userdata.*, (select sum(expense) from expense where expense.user_id=userdata.id) as expense FROM `userdata`
```

Or by using left join

```
SELECT u.*, sum(e.expense) as expense FROM `userdata` u left join expense e on e.user_id=u.id group by u.id
```

Here is the full Example of above query **(NOTE - PLEASE CHANGE COLUMN NAME ACCORDING TO YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE)**.

**User table**

[image]

**Expense Table**

[image]

Then run the query

```
SELECT userdata.*, (select sum(expense) from expense where expense.user_id=userdata.id) as expense FROM `userdata`
```

**Response**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.Name,
    t1.Email,
    t1.Address,
    t1.Designation
    COALESECE(t2.expenses, 0) AS Expense
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(Expense) AS expenses
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id;
```

We could also write the above without a subquery, using a direct join with aggregation.  But, with so many columns having appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, I prefer the version I gave.

Comment: Thanks for coment but @shubhum715 query works for me